# can't concatenate __LINE__ in macro

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

 #define STR_HELPER(x) #x
 #define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)
 #define (__FILE__ ": " STR(__LINE__))

int main()
{
   std::cout << FILE_LOCATION << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

output:
main.cpp : **__LINE__Var+1**

---

Why line no doesn't shown?

Comment: `#define (__FILE__ ": " STR(__LINE__))` umm, what??

Comment: There is simply no way the code you've shown us produces that output.

Comment: Right defenition is #define FILE_LOCATION (__FILE__ ": " STR(__LINE__)). I did mistake when was writing question, but source code has correct defenition. By the way, I'm using visual studio 6

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define your FILE_LOCATION macro, I cannot see the code where you define it in your snippet.
But wouldn't the code below do it?

```
 #define FILE_LOCATION __FILE__ ": " STR(__LINE__)
```